# Adding a Domain to AmazonSES for Verification from PHP/AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to add a domain for verification to my Amazon SES account from PHP. I tried using the following code:

```
$result = $amazonSesClient->verifyDomainDkim([
'Domain' => 'mydomain.com', // REQUIRED
]);
```

But it resulted in this (note that there are no domains for verification available on the SES account at this time):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\Ses\Exception\SesException' with message 'Error executing "PutIdentityPolicy" on "https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidPoli (truncated...)
 InvalidPolicy (client): Unable to parse policy. - <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidPolicy</Code>
    <Message>Unable to parse policy.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>a900a249-f032-11e5-85bd-77394342cf29</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
'

exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidPoli (truncated...)
' in in /var/www/html/bin/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 159
```

If I add the domain manually, it returns the DKIM as it's supposed to, but how do I add it programmatically? The documentation makes it sound like that method is supposed to add the domain for verification and then return it's DKIM records?

Answer (score 0):

Use verifyDomainIdentity() instead, with same paramaters, then make the second request to get the DKIM data.